# Can we host Hyperledger Fabric application like usual application with centralized backend?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm still new with hyperledger fabric, but I'm trying to make a web application with Hyperledger Fabric as the backend system. While I'm learning about this mechanism, I got confused about how to connect each peers as the server-side with client-side application. There's no problem when we connect them locally, but what about we do this while the client-side is accessed with another PC. With centralized backend and without more than 1 node server, we only need to move our resource to a hosting service.

Can we host this client-side application and connect with api service that each peers provide?

Answer (score 0):

The subject isn't as obvious as expected. Currently I am writing engineering thesis related to HLF and have a lot of "fun" with that.

There is unfortunately lack of enough practical examples that could help us deal with that problem you mentioned, but I was thinking and researching a lot and..

1. Assuming that peers of one org are running on the one host in separate containers, you have to expose specific ports of these peers(and orderer) outside this host. On the another host(with client, e.g. Java Fabric Gateway SDK app) you have to provide correct .ccp config file.
   *.ccp file contains configuration of the network that you want to connect with, specific ports and ip addresses of particular peers. Here is the link to *.ccp template: [Link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-2.2/test-network/organizations/ccp-template.json)
2. If you want to store peer and orderer nodes on separate machines, then you will have more things to do, because you have to keep each host in one "private" network.

If I could recommend you something, it would be: try deploy and connect two orgs' peers and orderers on two separate VMs, but on one computer. Additionaly you can place the client of this network on the third VM.

In the next step you can move forward and try with different computers in one local network. If you want to, inform about progress. I'm very curious about this problem's solution.

If it helps here is my repo with system that I build:
[Link](https://github.com/ninjavaz/healthchain)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and repo that you send me. I think I need to explore more about that first. Maybe if I got more insight about connecting two orgs' with different computers in one local network, I'll tell you more about that!